# Get the n top elements from a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm using the following example for demonstration purposes.

```
 [["apple",10],
 ["oranges",5],
 ["strawberies",2],
 ["pineapples",12],
 ["bananas",9],
 ["tomattoes",8],
 ["watermelon",1],
 ["mangos",7],
 ["grapes",11],
 ["potattoes",3]]
```

I want to get say the top 3 fruits by quantity (top 3 elements returned), however i don't want the order to change.
So the end result will be

```
[["apple",10],
 ["pineapples",12],
 ["grapes",11]]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the edits to be made on the array or in a seperate one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [["apple",10],
 ["oranges",5],
 ["strawberies",2],
 ["pineapples",12],
 ["bananas",9],
 ["tomattoes",8],
 ["watermelon",1],
 ["mangos",7],
 ["grapes",11],
 ["potattoes",3]]

sorted_arr = sorted(arr,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[:3]
output = [elem for elem in arr if elem in sorted_arr]
print(sorted_arr)
print(output)
```

First, we sort the array in reverse order to get the first 3 elements. Then, we use list comprehension to loop through the original array and check if the elements are in the top 3. This preserves the order.

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably heard before there is a sort method that you can apply to lists. You can pass in the key as a function that will indicate how you want your list to be sorted.

```
l = [["apple",10],
 ["oranges",5],
 ["strawberies",2],
 ["pineapples",12],
 ["bananas",9],
 ["tomattoes",8],
 ["watermelon",1],
 ["mangos",7],
 ["grapes",11],
 ["potattoes",3]]

l.sort(key = lambda x: x[1]) #to sort by second element
result = l[-3:] # To get the top three elements
```